# Bing maps v8 event passes incorrect pin?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

So I'm writing an app using bing maps v8. Unfortunately, it does not have z-index support (despite having z-index functions ...). So I am trying to use layers to accomplish something similar. The issue is when I swap a pin between layers the event begins firing on the correct pin location with the wrong metadata.

Here is how I create the pin

```
function createImagePin(location, index, objArray)
{
    var obj = objArray[index];
    var smallPin = getSmallPin(obj);

    var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location,
    {
        visible: true,
        icon: smallPin.data,
        anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(smallPin.width / 2, smallPin.height / 2) //Align center of pushpin with location.
    });

    pin.metadata = {};
    pin.metadata.index = index;
    pin.metadata.dataTarget = obj;
    pin.metadata.isSelected = false;

    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', function (e) {

        if(e.targetType === 'pushpin')
        {
            SetRowSelection(e.target.metadata.index);
        }
    });

    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'mouseover', function (e)
    {
        if(e.targetType === 'pushpin')
        {
            SelectPin(e.target); 
            ShowInfobox(e.target);
            console.log(e.target.getLocation());
        }
    });

    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'mouseout', function (e)
    {
        if (e.targetType === 'pushpin')
        {
            DeselectPin(e.target);
            HideInfobox();
        }
    });

    return pin;
}
```

For some reason I keep getting a pin object in the mouseover every time that has the correct location but the incorrect metadata. If I comment out Deselect ... I get the correct both.

Here is how I select and deselect the pin. Based on the example I was given [Bing Maps pushpin icon issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124293/bing-maps-pushpin-icon-issues/42126516?noredirect=1#comment71453685_42126516)

There is NO other code that is touching these pins at the moment ... It seems pretty bizarre to me. It is almost like internally it is only copying some information within the Layer rather then moving all items attached to the object. In fact, if I just comment out the add/remove it stops passing me incorrect data ... though i lose my z-indexing.

```
function SelectPin(pin)
{
    switch (pin.metadata.dataTarget.ComparableType)
    {
        case "Subject":
            mapLayers.subjectLayer.remove(pin);
            pin.setOptions({ visible: true, icon: largeGreenHouse.data, anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(largeGreenHouse.width / 2, largeGreenHouse.height / 2) });
            break;
        case "Listing Comp":
            mapLayers.compLayer.remove(pin);
            pin.setOptions({ visible: true, icon: largeBlueHouse.data, anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(largeBlueHouse.width / 2, largeBlueHouse.height / 2) });
            break;
        case "Sales Comp":
            mapLayers.compLayer.remove(pin);
            pin.setOptions({ visible: true, icon: largeBlueHouse.data, anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(largeBlueHouse.width / 2, largeBlueHouse.height / 2) });
            break;
        case "Hidden":
            pin.setOptions({ visible: false });
            return;
        default:
            mapLayers.observableLayer.remove(pin);
            pin.setOptions({ visible: true, icon: largeGreyHouse.data, anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(largeGreyHouse.width / 2, largeGreyHouse.height / 2) });
            break;
    }

    mapLayers.selectionLayer.add(pin);
    pin.metadata.isSelected = true;
}

function DeselectPin(pin)
{
    if(!pin.metadata.isSelected)
        return;

    pin.metadata.isSelected = false;
    mapLayers.selectionLayer.remove(pin);  
    switch (pin.metadata.dataTarget.ComparableType)
    {
        case "Subject":
            pin.setOptions({ visible: true, icon: greenHouse.data, anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(greenHouse.width / 2, greenHouse.height / 2) });
            mapLayers.subjectLayer.add(pin);
            break;
        case "Listing Comp":
            pin.setOptions({ visible: true, icon: blueHouse.data, anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(blueHouse.width / 2, blueHouse.height / 2) });
            mapLayers.compLayer.add(pin);
            break;
        case "Sales Comp":
            pin.setOptions({ visible: true, icon: blueHouse.data, anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(blueHouse.width / 2, blueHouse.height / 2) });
            mapLayers.compLayer.add(pin);
            break;
        case "Hidden":
            pin.setOptions({ visible: false });
            return;
        default:
            pin.setOptions({ visible: true, icon: greyHouse.data, anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(greyHouse.width / 2, greyHouse.height / 2) });
            mapLayers.observableLayer.add(pin);
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, it appears to be a data issue not a code issue. My data is getting geocoded into identical lat/long for some properties that don't have the same addresses. As such the rearranging of the array results in a different one with the same position getting 'top position'.